# Swipe для части экрана

Tags: android, swipe

Нужно сделать свайп на нижней части экрана для `LinearLayout` с дочерними view. В примере ниже `LinearLayout` `ll` занимает нижнюю половину экрана. Но свайп работает на всем экране благодаря `dispatchTouchEvent`. Не могу понять как нужно сделать, чтобы свайп работал только на `ll` и дочерних `view`. Без метода dispatchTouchEvent свайп не работает на дочерних `view` `LinearLayout`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        lSwipeDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());

        ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return lSwipeDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
}

   private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)               // вертикальный свайп
            return false;
        // слева направо <-
        if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Toast.makeText(Picker.this, "<-",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // справа налево ->
        else if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Toast.makeText(Picker.this, "->",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return lSwipeDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На нужном view

```
view.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

и метод

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
float x = event.getX();
float y = event.getY();
String sDown = "";
String sMove = "";
String sUp = "";

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
            sDown = "Down: " + x + "," + y;
            sMove = ""; sUp = "";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
            sMove = "Move: " + x + "," + y;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            sMove = "";
            sUp = "Up: " + x + "," + y;
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Теперь просто играете с х и у
Например:
если у нажатия меньше у отпускания и разница между ними больше скажем 120
то это свайп вниз. Ну смысл думаю поняли.

Comment: Данный метод работает на родителе. У меня LinearLayout с заполненными картинками, на которых назначен метод onClick. Если назначить onTouch на linearLayout, то он работает только, на нем, а на дочерних картинках не отрабатывает. Если и картинкам присвоить view.setOnTouchListener(this); тогда перестает работать обработчик нажатий onClick. Как их подружить?

Comment: Спасибо. Вы очень помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось подружить onTouchListner и onClickListener. Нужно в методе onTouch, если расстояние свайпа меньше какого то значения(130), то вернуть false. Тогда OnTouch позволит передать действие в onClickListener.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float x1=0,x2=0;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
            x1 = event.getX();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание
            x2 = event.getX();

            if (x1 - x2 > 130) { // код для перемещения вправо     

            }
            else if (x2 - x1 > 130) { //код для перемещения влево                                                          

            }
            else { // если это не движение(а нажатие)                        
                return false; // то возвращаем false, что позволит отработать другим обработчикам  
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: лучше не использовать числа "с потолка" вместо 130 используйте скажем какую-то часть от ширины/высоты экрана

Comment: Дельный совет, спасибо. Воспользуюсь.